# Error: "could not find function "separate_rows" " when using separate_rows() function

Tags: r

Why am I having this error:

> Error in separate_rows(Survey_responses, Usage_context, sep = ",") : 
>     could not find function "separate_rows"

when I run this line of code:

```
questionnaire_instagram <- separate_rows(Survey_responses, Usage_context, sep=",")
```

Am I missing a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, welcome to so, this question will probably be deleted, you are missing the tidyr library, you can call it using library(tidyverse) or library(tidyr)

```
questionnaire_instagram <- tidyr::separate_rows(Survey_responses, Usage_context, sep=",")
```